# How is android.Manifest.class created?

Tags: android

I can't find the android.Manifest.java in the source code directory? I can find AndroidManifest.xml in frameworks\base\core\res, I want to know how is android.Manifest.class created in android.jar.

Comment: what is this android.jar ? the official SDK doesn't deal with jars.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The permissions provided by the Android system can be found at Manifest.permission. I can't find the android.Manifest.java file in the source code directory,but i can see it(andord.Manifest.class) in android.jar provided by the Android SDK. So i'm confused.

Comment: @Ken what are you on? Of course the SDK has ".jars", how else would would you get access to the Android api's? When you select which API level to support in Eclipse, it adds the corresponding Jar from the SDK dir, for example *\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\android.jar*

Comment: @chrkad Platform.Version=4.1;Platform.CodeName=Jelly Bean;AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=16; I'm studying something about the android permission, so I was looking for the android.Manifest java file and my question appeared!Where is android.Manifest.java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any `android.Manifest.java` file, but when compiling AOSP there is a couple of `Manifest.java` files created automatically.

Perhaps this one is the one you're looking for? It seems to correspond to what's in android.jar (API 16)

`Manifest.class`
`Manifest$permission.class`
`Manifest$permission_group.class`

Located at `./out/target/common/R/android/Manifest.java`

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package android;

public final class Manifest {
public static final class permission {
    /**  Allow an application to read and write the cache partition.
     @hide 
     */
    public static final String ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM";
    /**  Allows read/write access to the "properties" table in the checkin
     database, to change values that get uploaded. 
     */
    public static final String ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES";
    /**  Allows an application to access coarse (e.g., Cell-ID, WiFi) location 
     */
    public static final String ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION";
    /**  Allows an application to access fine (e.g., GPS) location 
     */
    public static final String ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
    /**  Allows an application to access extra location provider commands 
     */
    public static final String ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS";
    /**  Allows an application to create mock location providers for testing 
     */
```

[rest cut due to exceeded post size]

Comment: And there's also a `Manifest.java` in the *sources* directory for the API-level (in the SDK); android-sdk\sources\android-16\java\util\jar\, that might be the one you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah!Thank you very much!That's what I need.OK,I should compile my AOSP and continue my study.LOL Thanks again!

Comment: I mean the ./out/target/common/R/android/Manifest.java.:)

Comment: The ./out/target/common/R/android/Manifest.java  suppose to be the correct   
 one, and items marked as @hide won't be in Manifest.class

Answer (score 0):

You can find the java files that make up android.jar in `\android-sdk\sources\android-15` (or whatever API you're building for). If the folder isn't there, install the source package from the SDK manager in eclipse.