# <uses-permission> vs <permission> in Android 6.0 Manifest.xml

Tags: java, android, permissions

i am aware that i have to use the new permission model with Android 6. (*check and request permission during runtime in the Activity or Fragment*)

My question is the generated `Manifest.java` file. When i use `<uses-permission>` it works with Android < 6.0 automatically but does not create those entries in the `Manifest.java` file and class. For this i have to use the `<permission>` tag in the Manifest xml file.

**Is this the normal way? Am i doing it right by using the extra `<permission>` tag?**

Because if i have to use both tags in the Manifest xml file, i am generating redundancies like that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

**UPDATE 1**

Okay, it seems that the `Manifest.java` is generated as soon as i add one `<permission>` tag to my Manifest.xml, which i am doing due to Mixpanels Cloud Messaging plugin that looks like that

```
<permission
    android:name=           "${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

**Is there a way to manually include the original Manifest.java located in /sdk/platforms/android-XX folder?**

Comment: Um, what is "the Manifest.java file and class"?

Comment: well, the 2nd line in the upper code generates a String `public static final String MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"` in the /build/generated/source/r/<package>/Manifest.java file... thats the String i shall use for `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` calls... i guess

Comment: I have never seen this `Manifest.java` file, sorry.

Comment: Oh okay. Thats strange.. but thanks god somebody else also has it :) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523542/how-is-android-manifest-class-created)

Comment: I think you just have to add a <permission> tag in the manifest, and that file gets generated by aapt

Answer (score 1):

**Permission**

Declares a security permission that can be used to limit access to specific components or features of this or other applications. See the [Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms) section in the introduction, and the [Security and Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html) document for more information on how permissions work.

**Uses Permission**

In some cases, the permissions that you request through  can affect how your application is filtered by Google Play.

If you request a hardware-related permission — CAMERA, for example — Google Play assumes that your application requires the underlying hardware feature and filters the application from devices that do not offer it.

To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in  elements, rather than relying on Google Play to "discover" the requirements in  elements. Then, if you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a android:required="false" attribute to the  declaration.

For a list of permissions that imply hardware features, see the documentation for the [uses-feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features) element.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my best solution for this right now is to use the following if i want to access Androids system permissions.

```
android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
```

And this type in order to access my custom permissions

```
<insert.packagename.here>.Manifest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

This way i can avoid redundant permission declarations in my Manifest.xml